# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error comes when retrieving and assigning a collection from firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a collection from Firebase Firestore and assign it to an array of type Category. But it gives an error: **Type of expression is ambiguous without more context**. Following is the related code.

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var categories: [Category] = [Category]() //Array of published categories
    
    private var categoriesDBReference = Firestore.firestore().collection("categories") //Reference to categories collection
    
    func fetch(){
        categoriesDBReference.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in //This line gives 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' error
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No documents retrieved when fetching all categories.")
                return
            }
            self.categories = documents.compactMap({ queryDocumentSnapshot -> Category? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Category.self)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code for **Category**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Category: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable{
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var categoryName: String?
}
```

The above error appears in the fetch function's `categoriesDBReference.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in` line.

I tried importing FirebaseFireStore, FirebaseFireStoreSwift, but then the line assigning the **categoriesDBReference** gives **Cannot find 'Firestore' in scope** error. I have confirmed that the collection and its documents exist in the database and the format in the firestore documents matches to that of **Category** object. In fact, when decoding manually, the error does not appear. Firebase was installed using the **Swift Package Manager**.

This approach of reading and assigning a collection from firestore has been mentioned in multiple places. I was expecting that this approach would make it easy to retrieve a collection and assign to a typed array of objects.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using? And do you have iOS simulator selected as device?

Comment: Xcode version is 14.3 and I do have iOS Simulator (iPhone 14 Pro) selected.

Comment: It's possible that this has nothing to do with Firebase, but XCode instead. Commenting out all the code and only have import at the top to see if that is allowed. I also found this: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/issues/4985#issuecomment-1507953206.

Comment: Only having the import is allowed with no errors or warnings. I tried adding Firebase according to the linked issue, but Firebase was not available to add and other firebase related packages like FirebaseFirestore, FirebaseFirestoreSwift were already there.

Answer (score 0):

These errors can be hard to correct because finding the culprit is not always obvious, and the Swift compiler certainly does not make it much easier. I've had these errors in the past and I was scratching my head forever because everything appeared correct. So I began refactoring everything and eventually the error went away after I took an if-else statement and broke it up. And this is also your culprit; the error is caused by your guard statement. You need to first unwrap the snapshot and then get its documents.

```
class CategoryViewModel: ObservableObject {
    ...

    func fetch() {
        categoriesDBReference.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let q = querySnapshot,
                  let documents = q.documents else {
                return
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but unfortunately the situation is still the same. Same error comes up in the same line.

Comment: @RavinduWataketiya it got rid of it for me using your code which means perhaps you have more of these semantic violations elsewhere in your code.

Comment: XCode didn't report any, and I did not find any myself. I tried commenting out the methods that I used for manual decoding, but the error was still the same.